# Passing parameters to the next ViewController with TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

[This code working very well] This is my situation: I have 2 view controllers, and the second must have TableView. In first view controller i have label and button, when I pressed him, he put me to the second view.Also i passing, when button was pressed: 2 parameters - current time, and another time, which was counted since the program was compile. And my problem is how to put this two parameters to tableView. It must work similar to MasterDetailApplication, where when you press + button it's create a Date in tableView. In my program it must create Date and time when i pressed button and go to the next ViewController. This is my code :

```
//Parameters.swift
import Foundation


struct Parameters {
    let toPass : String
    let toPass2: String  
}

//SecondViewController

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCounter: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        labelCounter.text = String(counter)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,target:self, selector: Selector("update"),userInfo: nil, repeats :true)   
    }

    func update(){            
        labelCounter.text = String(++counter)
        if counter == 15 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") { 
            var transfer = segue.destinationViewController as TableViewController
            transfer.toPass = labelCounter.text
            transfer.toPass2 = "\(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))"
        }
    }
 }


//TableViewCOntroller   
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    var toPass: String!
    var toPass2: String!
    var objects = [Parameters]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.objects = [Parameters(toPass: toPass2, toPass2: toPass)]
        // self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red :184.0, green: 219.0, blue: 243.0)
        //  self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        // tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var param : Parameters
        param = objects[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = param.toPass
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = param.toPass2 + " sec"
        return cell
    }
}
```

But I have another problem: when I put my button, and when I move to the tableViewController, how to do that my 2 parameters will be saved and stay in that tableViewController? When I close the app, this parameters are lost. How could I save them?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking as you don't seem tons e a question here, but I suspect you are finding that your properties aren't set in ThirdViewController - this is because you are accessing them in `viewDidLoad`. Try setting your labels in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: My problem is how when i pressed button from first view controller it will put me to the second view controller and attribute this two parameters to my tableView.

Comment: Your code looks correct assuming you have linked your button to a segue in the storyboard

Comment: Yes i had connected two view controller in the storyboard. But how to put this passed parameters to the tableVIew?;d

Comment: You haven't shown any table view code in third view controller.  What have you tried?  What is happening?

Comment: I changed my second view controller to the TableViewController. And now i don't know how to put this 2 parameters to this tableViewController.

Comment: Have you read the tableView programming guide or any tutorials?

Comment: That is what I'm doing wright now.

Comment: Make sure your segue ID matches the identifier in your storyboard

Comment: I just did this. My edit code was placed above.